# How many newsletters can I subscribe?

Tags: support, newsletter

I have subscribed 12 newsletters. And I want to know how many newsletters can I subscribe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As many as you want. There's no limit beyond the actual number of the sites we have, and even then you could subscribe multiple times for the same newsletter with different email addresses.

I don't know why you'd *want* to subscribe to 140+ newsletters, but hey. It's your inbox. :)

Comment: Thanks. I considered I have subscribed many newsletters and I worried about that I can't subscribe more.